# getting error ['djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported] wihile running makemigrations cmd in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have create one simple django project and try to connect with mongodb database
but when hit python manage.py makemigrations or migrate cmd getting error-

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

python python v- 3.10
please help me out.

pip list-

```
Package    Version
```

---

asgiref    3.6.0
Django     4.1.7
djongo     1.3.6
dnspython  2.3.0
pip        23.0.1
pymongo    4.3.3
setuptools 67.6.0
sqlparse   0.2.4
tzdata     2022.7

setting.py file db connection and install app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'dapp',
'djongo',
]



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'djongo',
      'NAME': 'testdb',
      'HOST': 'localhost',
      'PORT': 27017,
  }
 }
```

Comment: djongo is package for connect mongodb

Comment: @ashish pandey try `pip install pytz`, after a quick google apparentl you need to install this dependency separately. Let me know if it worked and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: `djongo` shouldn't be on the `INSTALLED_APPS` https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django#connect-django-and-mongodb-using-djongo

Comment: after install pytz and run makemigrations cmd getting this error---           [NotImplementedError: Database objects do not implement truth value testing or bool(). Please compare with None instead: database is not None]

Comment: after reinstall  pymongo==3.12.3 issue resolve, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to install pytz
Open terminal and install pytz (pip install pytz)

Comment: after install pytz and run makemigrations cmd getting this error--- [NotImplementedError: Database objects do not implement truth value testing or bool(). Please compare with None instead: database is not None]

Comment: after reinstall pymongo==3.12.3 issue resolve, thanks

Answer (score 1):

install pytz, and install pymongo==3.12.3

Since you resolved the issue, wouldn't that make the pymongo library outdated??

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install djongo==1.3.6
```

This helped me to solve the problem, I installed the most recent version of "djongo